# Prepend a character if string exists otherwise not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to prepend a '/' if the variable follow has a value otherwise if it is nil then keep it as nil

```
    l2, follow = params[:all].split('/', 2)
    follow     = follow.nil? ? follow : "/#{follow}"
    redirect_to "#{my_path(locale: locale, l2: l2)}#{rest}"
```

the params[:all] here could be a url path like

```
esp
esp/article/1
esp/article/1/author/1
```

EDIT:
My approach works but would like to know if there is a better way

Comment: but you're actually doing it in the following line `follow.nil? ? follow : "/#{follow}"`. This approach doesn't work?

Comment: it works fine, I just want to know if there is a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
follow.nil? ? follow : "/#{follow}"
```

Since `Ruby` has [String#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-prepend) method, the code can be refactored the following way:

```
follow && follow.prepend("/")
```

Or since `Ruby 2.3` has safe navigation, it can be expressed even more concise:

```
follow&.prepend("/")
```

Comment: follow &&= follow.prepend('/')

Comment: looks fine, but `prepend` actually mutates the variable, so there's no need in assigning

Comment: `follow &&= "/#{follow}"` is a nice option too: prepend is the better specialized choice here, but `&&=` would work with more arbitrary manipulation (and avoid mutating the original string, where that's a concern)

Comment: Just to clarify, that would be follow && follow.prepend('/')  Right?